# why is this error occurring: '@+id/' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference

Tags: android

I see several others have asked this question (and also on an Android Forum).

Previously I have installed the app on my phone (Galaxy A51) with no problems. I rebuilt the app. It can run in an emulator but now I get this error: '@+id/' is incompatible with attribute id (attr) reference

No idea what this refers to or how to fix it?

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your XML views?

Comment: Do you have `android:id="@+id/"` somewhere as the full ID in an XML (instead of something like `android:id="@+id/foo"`)? That's what the error would indicate.

Comment: There is no android:id="@+id/" as the full XML.

Comment: Then you're going to have to share the XML for anyone to be able to say anything beyond that. Also, if you see that several others have asked this, include those links in your question. All the cases I've seen that error means the ID isn't a properly formatted ID string.

Comment: Actually there is android:id="@+id/". THANKS!!!!

Comment: No problem - added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML for

```
android:id="@+id/"
```

and replace it with a properly formatted ID string, like

```
android:id="@+id/foo"
```

That error means the string you provided for an `android:id` attribute is not formatted the way an ID string should be, and the error message tells you that the offending string is `"@+id/"`, so you can search for that to find it and fix it. There is some information on formatting it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource#idvalue)

> For the ID value, you typically use this syntax form: "@+id/name", as shown in the following example. The plus symbol, +, indicates that this is a new resource ID, and the aapt tool creates a new resource integer in the R.java class, if it doesn't already exist.